# My Android App is not showing up in HTC Inspire 2.2.1 Android Market Application

Tags: android

I looked at other posts who have similar issues. I understand that in those cases it is because of not mentioning properly the minSdk version. But in my case i have the following.

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="9"/>

<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

But it is still not showing up in HTC Inspire. Earlier i use to have minSDkVersion = "3". I changed it even though my app works well on 1.5 devices.

I even tried as mentioned in one of the examples for compatibility in Android Website

```
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4"/>
```

without support Screens element. The website said, doing like this it will show up on all devices. But this didnt help. My guess is that My app might not be showing up on many other devices.

Can somebody help me.

Comment: Can you post your entire `AndroidManifest.xml`? Sometimes certain permissions, libraries and other such declarations can cause this type of problems. You can edit out any sensitive information, if that's a problem.

Comment: I hope this will be useful for someone who is struggling with this issue. I selected Copy Protection on while publishing my Android App. That caused my App not show up on devices which support copy of your Android application. When i chose Off for copy protection, it started to show up across all the devices.

Comment: Because you're new to Stackoverflow, I'm going to tell you what you should do: you should write an answer to your own question where you explain that turning off copy protection fixed the problem, and then mark it as the accepted answer.